# Difference between object and array when importing JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, object, nsmutablearray

I am trying to follow [this](http://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/#insertdata) tutorial for importing data from JSON and realize I don't fundamentally understand the difference between an array and an object.  After you have captured the JSON feed into an array, what are you doing by creating an object?  What is the difference between the object and the array?

Here is the code that turns the array into an object.  Would appreciate someone explaining why it is necessary and what you are really doing here...

```
// Parse the JSON that came in
NSError *error;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_downloadedData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
/*If you log out this array, you see something that looks like JSON as in  {
   name = "Googleplex";
   location = "100 Ampitheatre";
   }, etc.
*/
// Loop through Json objects, create objects and add the to our array
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++)
{
    NSDictionary *jsonElement = jsonArray[i];

    // Create a new location object and set its props to JsonElement properties
    Location *newLocation = [[Location alloc] init];
    newLocation.name = jsonElement[@"Name"];
    newLocation.address = jsonElement[@"Address"];

    // Add this question to the locations array
    [_locations addObject:newLocation];
}
```

Comment: You haven't at all explained what you're trying to achieve, or where your definitions of things come from.

Comment: First line of question:  'I am trying to follow this tutorial'  Code is from tutorial.

Comment: @Wain, the tutorial from codewithchris explains how to capture a json feed and display it in a table.  You get the JSON feed as an array from NSJSON serialization.  Chris' code suggests you need to convert the array so captured into an object, new location with elements corresponding to the fields in the JSON.  My question is why you do that and what is the difference between the object and the array.  I have seen other tutorials where they display directly from the array without creating an object in between.  Presumably there is some added value and I am trying to grasp what it is.

Comment: You don't need to, it depends what you want to do with the data and what the app data model is like. The value is in a 'strongly typed' or specific data model.